# Capacitor discharge after charge

Tags: capacitor, discharge

I have this circuit for charging a capacitor:
[image: capacitor charge circuit]

What I need is a circuit for discharging the capacitor after 'V' (the voltage across the 100 µF capacitor) has reached the maximum value of 2V. I know a discharge circuit can be implemented by NPN transistors, but I am not getting how. Guidance required.

The capacitor should only discharge when 'V' reaches 2V.

Comment: Do you want this to happen automatically/repetitively? Or like a camera flash where you press a button to discharge when the cap is charged up?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure the voltage over the capacitor unless it is separated from the battery. In theory it is possible when you make a discharge circuit which 'cuts' the charge wires, but it won't work with your circuit.

Comment: there should be some way i can harness the charge stored by the capacitor when it is fully charged... Something like camera flash circuit..

Comment: There is a difference between _charge_ and _voltage_, you know that? Voltage is an electrical power, while charge is the amount of electrons stored.

Comment: I know.. How do I implement something like "camera flash circuit" using simple BJT's?

Comment: You might want to ask a new question about that, since it is really a different question. List the requirements, etc.