# Is it possible to measure a capacitors voltage while charging it?

Tags: capacitor

Lets say you have a simple circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuwJOd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it possible to get any other voltage reading from this loop than source+ or source-? adding another resistor is not an option

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. The obvious answer is that you can put a multimeter between any two points and measure the voltage between those points. But I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for. What are you measuring *with*?

Comment: I'm trying to design a power supply and figured i would charge the cap to say 50v and then cut off but how would i figure out when its at 50v? The measurement would taken by a differential signal between the cap and ref voltage.

Comment: So you have to measure *with something*. What are you using to measure? A multimeter and your eyes? A comparator? A microcontroller and A/D converter?

Comment: I don't understand.  Put a multimeter or scope accross the cap.  This is so obvious that it is unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Looking at your schematic, the steady-state voltage across that cap is going to be the same as your source voltage. There is no way to alter this without altering the circuit. Further, the time constant of that circuit is going to be 100 uS. If you're reading that with a multimeter, the cap will charge to the source voltage well before the meter can respond. So if you're using a meter, all you'll ever see across that cap is the source voltage.

Is that actually what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to measure the voltage across the capacitor (from the resistor-capacitor node to the source- node), but of course any real measurement will disturb what is happening, however slightly.

It's quite easy to get a very accurate measurement of a 1uF capacitor being charged with 10uA. Measuring a 0.1pF capacitor being charged with 1mA is accurately (to better than +/-10%) without greatly disturbing what is going on is close to impossible. Even an active FET oscilloscope probe will have a pF or so of input capacitance.

Comment: i tried that but it only seems to work while not charging, while charging i always get the voltage of the source im charging with.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: It sounds like you are measuring the wrong place!

Comment: Maybe it charged so fast that you missed it.

Comment: @Karli: What Spehro said. With 100 Ohms and 1 uF, the time constant is 100 us. The cap will have long charged to the voltage source level by the time you put a meter on it and get a reading. However, that's plenty slow enough to see it charge up with a scope. At 50 us per division, you should see a nice exponential.

Answer (score 0):

A voltage can be measured between any two points. Yes, you can measure the voltage across the capacitor. You can also measure it across the resistor. You can also measure it across the power supply. You can also measure it between your foot and the node between the resistor and the supply (although that's probably not a useful option).

Since this is such a simple circuit, it's also simple to calculate voltages, if you know something else. [Kirchhoff's voltage law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29) tells us that the voltage across the resistor, plus the voltage across the capacitor must equal V1:

$$ V_{R1} + V_{C1} = V_1 $$

So, if measuring the capacitor voltage is not convenient for you, perhaps you can measure the resistor voltage, and since V1 is probably constant, you can calculate the capacitor voltage.

[Kirchhoff's current law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29) also tells us that the current anywhere in this series circuit is equal. So, if you have some means of knowing the current, then you could calculate the voltage across the resistor by [Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). Then, you could calculate the voltage across the capacitor as above.

However, from your comments it sounds like you want to do this to convert a higher voltage to a lower voltage. That won't be any better than using an ordinary [linear regulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator). The reason is that the voltage conversion happens by converting electrical energy to heat in R1. There is no solution to this without adding inductance, as in a [buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter).

For more on why this can't be better than a linear regulator, see [Can a charge-pump be 100% efficient, given ideal components?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/54992/17608)