# Charge-pump capacitor power dissipation in voltage converters

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, dc-dc-converter

Here
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/725
and here
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3603.pdf

The same calculation for the power dissipation given by the pump capacitor in a switching capacitor voltage regulator is made.

What I don't understand, is how a lossless component becomes a lossy component. It is said that the equivalent resistance is not just something that gives you the same RMS current, but it also models the power loss given by switching the capacitor.

It might be the power lost in the ESR or in the Ron of the switches, I thought at first, but these losses are already took into account by other factors explained in other parts of the documents.

So, what other effect does the factor \$ I_{load}*f*C_{pump} \$ really take into account?

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor is essentially a lossless element.  And if you have a current source for charging it (like a switched inductor can be), the charge process is comparatively lossless as well.  The loss comes into play when you have a voltage source for charging it since the potential difference to the capacitor is larger than necessary at every moment of charging. This difference has to go somewhere. If the resistance of the connections into the capacitor is effectively zero, its inductance will cause oscillation that ends up emitting the excess energy as RF radiation due to the electric field in the capacitor and the magnetic field from the connections to it (and the displacement current across it).

It is not the capacitor that becomes lossy, it is that combining a voltage source and a capacitor for charging it is more likely than not lossy (with a switched inductor for charging the capacitor being a pretty good path to high efficiency).

Answer (score 0):

The process of charging a capacitor via a resistor, even if the resistor is very small, produces an energy (or IIR) loss each cycle. An inductor based switching regulator doesn’t suffer from this theoretical loss because the energy that can be put into an inductor by connecting it momentarily across a supply voltage (as in the case of a boost regulator), is performed losslessly.

Going back to the charging capacitor scenario, it’s an interesting subject that has accrued several questions on this site and, it can be shown that whatever value of series charging resistor, the energy lost per cycle in the resistor is the same. Basically, the energy taken from the supply voltage to top up the capacitor is always more than what eventually gets stored in the capacitor hence, it takes on the mantle of an inefficient component even though theoretically that inefficiency is external to the capacitor.

Comment: However, the loss that you mentioned in a simple RC circuit can be taken into account by the power loss on the resistor. In the case of the pump capacitor, the loss on all the resistors that are in the path of charge and discharge of the capacitor is already taken into account by the other factors. So it seems that I*f*C is taking into account a loss of a different nature. Isn't it?

Comment: @Elia See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/55001